# Is Eclipse's $SWITCH_TABLE$ thread-safe?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-memory-model

It appears when Eclipse compiles an enum whose values are used in a `switch` statement, it adds the following to the enum class file:

- synthetic field: `private static int[] $SWITCH_TABLE$mypackage$MyEnum;`
- synthetic method: `static int[] $SWITCH_TABLE$mypackage$MyEnum()`
  Lazily initializes `$SWITCH_TABLE$mypackage$MyEnum` field with respective enum ordinal values.

And at every place where a switch on the enum values occurs it calls `$SWITCH_TABLE$mypackage$MyEnum()[e.ordinal()]`.

Source code:

```
package mypackage;

public enum MyEnum {
    FIRST;

    public int get() {
        switch (this) {
            case FIRST:
                return 2;
            default:
                return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Decompiled code:

```
package mypackage;

public enum MyEnum {
   FIRST;

   // $FF: synthetic field
   private static int[] $SWITCH_TABLE$mypackage$MyEnum;

   public int get() {
      switch($SWITCH_TABLE$mypackage$MyEnum()[this.ordinal()]) {
      case 1:
         return 2;
      default:
         return -1;
      }
   }

   // $FF: synthetic method
   static int[] $SWITCH_TABLE$mypackage$MyEnum() {
      int[] var10000 = $SWITCH_TABLE$mypackage$MyEnum;
      if (var10000 != null) {
         return var10000;
      } else {
         int[] var0 = new int[values().length];

         try {
            var0[FIRST.ordinal()] = 1;
         } catch (NoSuchFieldError var1) {
         }

         $SWITCH_TABLE$mypackage$MyEnum = var0;
         return var0;
      }
   }
}
```

However, as you can see here neither the field `$SWITCH_TABLE$mypackage$MyEnum` is `volatile` nor `$SWITCH_TABLE$mypackage$MyEnum()` is performing any sychronization.

The question is now: Is this actually thread-safe? If I understand the Java Memory Model correctly, there is no guarantee that if one thread initializes the switch table (through a call to `get()`), a second thread sees an up to date switch table value. Instead it might see a stale value which does not have the correct elements.

Followup question: Since there are no *happens-before*  relations, would a JVM also be allowed to reorder the assignment to the `$SWITCH_TABLE$` in front of the element changes? If this was possible there could be race conditions where one thread sees the array while the other thread is still modifying the elements.

Comment: I do not think that its values will ever be changed... so it should be thread-safe (it may be created two or more times in parallel, but since the content is always the same, that is just sub-optimal)

Comment: The array elements are changed. When it is initialized all elements will be 0 and afterwards the values for the enum value ordinals are set. So (if I understand it correctly) it would be possible that a second thread sees that the array is initialized, but does not see the change to its elements.

Comment: @Marcono1234 I think that your understanding is correct, however there's no actual risk involved since the worst case scenario is that a thread sees the field as `null` when in fact it has already been initialized by another thread. In that case, it will just re-initialize it with a new array with the same value. There's no risk of initiating the field to a wrong value at any point.

Comment: @Malt, that would indeed not be a problem, but this is not what I meant. I am talking about the second thread seeing only that the field is non-null, but not seeing all changes to the elements, i.e. for  some enum values the array would still contain 0.

Comment: that can not happen, see how it is creating the array in a local variable (`var0`) which is only assigned to the field after the array being completely filled. The only *risk* is that the variable gets assigned more than once (with array containing the same values), that is, more than one array will be created, but values are the exact same

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I'm not sure that's right. There's no happens-before relationship between filling the array and the write to the static field since the field isn't volatile. Therefore, these writes can be reordered by the compiler.

Comment: Of course they can be wrong. You're talking about "program order" which relates to a *single thread*. Without the field being volatile or final, there's no guarantee that other threads will see the same sequence of events. Take a look at example Example 17.4.5-1 in chapter 17 of the JLS.

Answer (score 0):

I run some tests with [jcstress](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/CodeTools/jcstress) on Windows 7/OpenJDK 13. The local variables are important!

This code should mimic posted code, running 3 threads, multiple times:

```
// concurrency stress test
@JCStressTest

// expected outcome (III_Result::toString)
@Outcome(id = "1, 1, 1", expect = Expect.ACCEPTABLE, desc = "Correctly initialized.")
@Outcome(id = ".+, .+, .+", expect = Expect.FORBIDDEN, desc = "Some Thread did see a not initialized array")

// test data
@State
public class EnumInitOK {

    int[] array;

    int[] switchTable() {
        int[] v1 = array;
        if (v1 != null) {
            return v1;
        } else {
            int[] v2 = new int[1];
            v2[0] = 1;
            array = v2;
            return v2;
        }
    }

    // each called only by one particular Thread, once per State instance
    @Actor public void test1(III_Result r) {
        r.r1 = switchTable()[0];
    }

    @Actor public void test2(III_Result r) {
        r.r2 = switchTable()[0];
    }

    @Actor public void test3(III_Result r) {
        r.r3 = switchTable()[0];
    }
}
```

Results from all runs with different settings, not one initialization error (almost 400M tests):

> ```
> Java Concurrency Stress Tests
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Rev: null, built by cfh with 12.0.2 at null
>
> Probing what VM modes are available:
>  (failures are non-fatal, but may miss some interesting cases)
>
> ----- [OK] [-Xint]
> ----- [OK] [-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1]
> ----- [OK] []
> ----- [OK] [-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions, -XX:+StressLCM, -XX:+StressGCM]
> ----- [OK] [-XX:-TieredCompilation]
> ----- [OK] [-XX:-TieredCompilation, -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions, -XX:+StressLCM, -XX:+StressGCM]
>
> Initializing and probing the target VM: 
>  (all failures are non-fatal, but may affect testing accuracy)
>
> ----- [OK] Unlocking diagnostic VM options
> Burning up to figure out the exact CPU count....... done!
>
> ----- [OK] Trimming down the default VM heap size to 1/4-th of max RAM
> ----- [OK] Trimming down the number of compiler threads
> ----- [OK] Trimming down the number of parallel GC threads
> ----- [OK] Trimming down the number of concurrent GC threads
> ----- [OK] Trimming down the number of G1 concurrent refinement GC threads
> ----- [OK] Testing @Contended works on all results and infra objects
> ----- [OK] Unlocking Whitebox API for online de-optimization
> ----- [OK] Testing allocation profiling
> ----- [OK] Trying Thread.onSpinWait
>
>   Hardware threads in use/available: 4/4, using Thread.onSpinWait()
>   Test preset mode: "default"
>   Writing the test results to "jcstress-results-2019-10-22-23-32-40.bin.gz"
>   Parsing results to "results/"
>   Running each test matching "cfh.jcstress.EnumInitOK" for 1 forks, 5 iterations, 1000 ms each
>   Each JVM would execute at most 5 tests in the row.
>   Solo stride size will be autobalanced within [10, 10000] elements, but taking no more than 100 Mb.
>
> ... [output deleted] ...
>
> RUN COMPLETE.
>
> RUN RESULTS:
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> *** INTERESTING tests
>   Some interesting behaviors observed. This is for the plain curiosity.
>
>   0 matching test results. 
>
> *** FAILED tests
>   Strong asserts were violated. Correct implementations should have no assert failures here.
>
>   0 matching test results. 
>
> *** ERROR tests
>   Tests break for some reason, other than failing the assert. Correct implementations should have none.
>
>   0 matching test results. 
>
> *** All remaining tests
>   Tests that do not fall into any of the previous categories.
>
>   6 matching test results. 
>       [OK] cfh.jcstress.EnumInitOK
>     (JVM args: [-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions, -XX:+StressLCM, -XX:+StressGCM])
>   Observed state   Occurrences   Expectation  Interpretation                                              
>       .+, .+, .+             0     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          1, 1, 1    76.194.931    ACCEPTABLE  Correctly initialized.                                      
>
>       [OK] cfh.jcstress.EnumInitOK
>     (JVM args: [-XX:-TieredCompilation, -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions, -XX:+StressLCM, -XX:+StressGCM])
>   Observed state   Occurrences   Expectation  Interpretation                                              
>       .+, .+, .+             0     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          1, 1, 1    76.756.011    ACCEPTABLE  Correctly initialized.                                      
>
>       [OK] cfh.jcstress.EnumInitOK
>     (JVM args: [-XX:-TieredCompilation])
>   Observed state   Occurrences   Expectation  Interpretation                                              
>       .+, .+, .+             0     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          1, 1, 1    78.453.381    ACCEPTABLE  Correctly initialized.                                      
>
>       [OK] cfh.jcstress.EnumInitOK
>     (JVM args: [-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1])
>   Observed state   Occurrences   Expectation  Interpretation                                              
>       .+, .+, .+             0     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          1, 1, 1    73.608.821    ACCEPTABLE  Correctly initialized.                                      
>
>       [OK] cfh.jcstress.EnumInitOK
>     (JVM args: [-Xint])
>   Observed state   Occurrences   Expectation  Interpretation                                              
>       .+, .+, .+             0     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          1, 1, 1     8.740.641    ACCEPTABLE  Correctly initialized.                                      
>
>       [OK] cfh.jcstress.EnumInitOK
>     (JVM args: [])
>   Observed state   Occurrences   Expectation  Interpretation                                              
>       .+, .+, .+             0     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          1, 1, 1    86.069.111    ACCEPTABLE  Correctly initialized.                                      
>
>
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

---

To cross-check, I tried the same code accessing the `array` directly, without using the local variables, in the `switchTable` method:

```
//concurrency stress test
@JCStressTest

//expected outcome (III_Result::toString)
@Outcome(id = "1, 1, 1", expect = Expect.ACCEPTABLE, desc = "Correctly initialized.")
@Outcome(id = ".+, .+, .+", expect = Expect.FORBIDDEN, desc = "Some Thread did see a not initialized array")

//test data
@State
public class EnumInitErr {

    int[] array;

    int[] switchTable() {
        if (array != null) {
            return array;
        } else {
            array = new int[1];
            array[0] = 1;
            return array;
        }
    }

    // each called only by one particular Thread, once per State instance
    @Actor public void test1(III_Result r) {
        r.r1 = switchTable()[0];
    }

    @Actor public void test2(III_Result r) {
        r.r2 = switchTable()[0];
    }

    @Actor public void test3(III_Result r) {
        r.r3 = switchTable()[0];
    }
}
```

This time we got some results with uninitialized arrays:

> ```
> ... [output deleted] ...
>
> RUN COMPLETE.
>
> RUN RESULTS:
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> *** INTERESTING tests
>   Some interesting behaviors observed. This is for the plain curiosity.
>
>   0 matching test results. 
>
> *** FAILED tests
>   Strong asserts were violated. Correct implementations should have no assert failures here.
>
>   6 matching test results. 
>   [FAILED] cfh.jcstress.EnumInitErr
>     (JVM args: [-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions, -XX:+StressLCM, -XX:+StressGCM])
>   Observed state   Occurrences   Expectation  Interpretation                                              
>          0, 0, 1           565     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          0, 1, 0         1.089     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          0, 1, 1         2.835     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          1, 0, 0           792     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          1, 0, 1         3.272     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          1, 1, 0         2.394     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          1, 1, 1    70.441.694    ACCEPTABLE  Correctly initialized.                                      
>
>   [FAILED] cfh.jcstress.EnumInitErr
>     (JVM args: [-XX:-TieredCompilation, -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions, -XX:+StressLCM, -XX:+StressGCM])
>   Observed state   Occurrences   Expectation  Interpretation                                              
>          0, 0, 1           481     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          0, 1, 0           604     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          0, 1, 1         2.373     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          1, 0, 0           901     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          1, 0, 1         2.908     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          1, 1, 0         3.310     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          1, 1, 1    69.456.024    ACCEPTABLE  Correctly initialized.                                      
>
>   [FAILED] cfh.jcstress.EnumInitErr
>     (JVM args: [-XX:-TieredCompilation])
>   Observed state   Occurrences   Expectation  Interpretation                                              
>          0, 0, 1         1.332     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          0, 1, 0           948     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          0, 1, 1         4.212     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          1, 0, 0         1.071     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          1, 0, 1         5.216     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          1, 1, 0         5.052     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          1, 1, 1    64.580.410    ACCEPTABLE  Correctly initialized.                                      
>
>   [FAILED] cfh.jcstress.EnumInitErr
>     (JVM args: [-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1])
>   Observed state   Occurrences   Expectation  Interpretation                                              
>          0, 0, 1         8.766     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          0, 1, 0        11.470     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          0, 1, 1        21.761     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          1, 0, 0        11.280     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          1, 0, 1        28.461     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          1, 1, 0        27.634     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          1, 1, 1    71.079.569    ACCEPTABLE  Correctly initialized.                                      
>
>   [FAILED] cfh.jcstress.EnumInitErr
>     (JVM args: [-Xint])
>   Observed state   Occurrences   Expectation  Interpretation                                              
>          0, 0, 1            77     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          0, 1, 0           117     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          0, 1, 1         2.417     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          1, 0, 0            83     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          1, 0, 1         2.291     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          1, 1, 0         1.789     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          1, 1, 1     5.674.177    ACCEPTABLE  Correctly initialized.                                      
>
>   [FAILED] cfh.jcstress.EnumInitErr
>     (JVM args: [])
>   Observed state   Occurrences   Expectation  Interpretation                                              
>          0, 0, 1           785     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          0, 1, 0           804     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          0, 1, 1         2.717     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          1, 0, 0         1.250     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          1, 0, 1         4.041     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          1, 1, 0         5.500     FORBIDDEN  Some Thread did see a not initialized array                 
>          1, 1, 1    63.510.464    ACCEPTABLE  Correctly initialized.                                      
>
>
> *** ERROR tests
>   Tests break for some reason, other than failing the assert. Correct implementations should have none.
>
>   0 matching test results. 
>
> *** All remaining tests
>   Tests that do not fall into any of the previous categories.
>
>   0 matching test results. 
>
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

<sub>first time using `jcstress`, sorry for any errors</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much! I now tested it as well and I think you need more than one "enum value" (i.e. more than one assignment) and also have to test the last enum value. I assume otherwise the code is executed too fast for any other thread to even have a chance to see the uninitialized state. I wrote a test myself now (https://github.com/Marcono1234/eclipse-enum-jcstress) and it appears it is not thread-safe (might have to run the test multiple times). Or do you see a mistake in the implementation?

Comment: I stay corrected - I have not yet tested it, but looks OK (not being `static` is the only possible flaw I can think of, also on my tests, but I don't believe that is a problem). I searched the internet and found [Bug 544521](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=544521) on Eclipse's Bugzilla - maybe you can add a comment linking to this question

Comment: Thanks for searching, I added a comment. Do you want to post the link to the bug report as a separate answer?